# Ignore hardcoded strings on logger statements-IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-inspection

On IntelliJ, I typically enable the inspection to find hard coded strings in Java projects. However, it can generate lot of false positives due to hard coded strings present in logger statements.

Is there any way in IntelliJ to ignore logger statements from this inspection ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can annotate the String parameter of the logger method with the @NonNls annotation. The *Hard coded strings* inspection will then ignore the strings present in logger calls. To annotate, position the text cursor on a warning and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select *Annotate parameter 'xxx' as @NonNls*.

Comment: I would think this as a workaround though, basically polluting the code with such extraneous annotation on every logger statement. I guess there is no official support on this from IntelliJ, so would be good to add this to their feature list. They should just have a regex based support for ignoring on the actual statements as well.

Comment: No, not on the logger statement, on the logger method. You add it from the call, but the annotation ends up on the method. Only one annotation is needed and **all** calls to the method are ignored.

Comment: Hmm..that might work. will try that out for now. Although, I would still prefer something like this is supported natively on IDE so the code is free from such extraneous details (for good reason :)). So definitely would vote for this as a feature enhancement on future IntelliJ versions.

Comment: You can store the annotations outside of the source code, using [External annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/external-annotations.html).

Comment: The annotation on the logger declaration works as well. So for instance the following works,

@NonNls
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);